# Randomize a List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to, given a list, create a random arrangement of that elements in Haskell. I already tried the algorithm in Javascript and it worked. I'm pretty new to Haskell so I might be not seeing something. I'm pretty sure that I'm receiving single elements instead of lists with just one element in it, which makes my program crash. I've encountered this problem in previous exercises but still do not know how to solve it.

The algorithm divides the list until it gets one element. Then there is a 50% chance of if merging the list as it was and another 50% to merge it the other way around.

This is the code:

```
-- A randomly chosen, program-scoped constant from the range [1 .. 10]
randomInt :: Int
randomInt = unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (1, 10)))

-- Divides the list in half
divideList :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
divideList list = splitAt ((length list) `div` 2) list

-- Given a list, it creates a new one with the elements of said list
randomizeList :: Eq a => a -> [a]
randomizeList list = do
    let lists = (divideList list) in
        if (length list) > 1
        then if (randomInt > 5)
        then (randomizeList (fst lists) : randomizeList (snd lists))
        else (randomizeList (snd lists) : randomizeList (fst lists))
        else [list]
```

Here is the Javascript code in case it helps:

```
function divideList(list){
    const length = list.length / 2;
    return {fst: list.splice(0, length), snd: list};
}
function randomizeList(list) {
    if(list.length == 1) return list;
    const lists = divideList(list);
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) return randomizeList(lists.fst).concat(randomizeList(lists.snd));
    else return randomizeList(lists.snd).concat(randomizeList(lists.fst));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You type signature is incorrect `randomizeList :: Eq a => a -> [a]` takes in a single element and returns a list, you probably wanted `[a] -> [a]`.  I also don't see why `Eq` is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems with your code, mostly trivial mistakes:

1. Wrong signature, should be `randomizeList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`
    (it's from list to list, not from element to list)
2. spurious `do` on the beginning of the block (just remove)
3. list are concatenated with `++`, not with `:` (the latter adds an element to a list)
4. in the last `else` you need to return `list` instead of `[list]` (the latter is a list of lists)

The following should work:

```
randomizeList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
randomizeList list =
  let lists = (divideList list) in
    if (length list) > 1
    then if (randomInt > 5)
    then (randomizeList (fst lists) ++ randomizeList (snd lists))
    else (randomizeList (snd lists) ++ randomizeList (fst lists))
    else list
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick and easy way to randomize a list would be:

```
module Main where                                                                                                                                                      

import Control.Monad (replicateM)                                                                                             
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List     (sortBy)
import System.Random (randomRIO)                                                                                                                                                     

main :: IO ()
main = do                                                                                                                                                              
  putStrLn "not randomized"                                                                                                                                            
  let nums = [1..10]                                                                                                                                                   
  print nums                                                                                                                                                           
  putStrLn "randomized"                                                                                                                                                
  print =<< randomize nums                                                                                                                                             

randomize :: [a] -> IO [a]                                                                                                                                             
randomize xs = do                                                                                                                                                      
  ys <- replicateM (length xs) $ randomRIO (1 :: Int, 100000)                                                                                                          
  pure $ map fst $ sortBy (compare `on` snd) (zip xs ys)
```

This code generates a random list of numbers, zips them with the original list, and then sorts these pairs by the random number generated. We then strip off the random number (`map fst`) and are left with the original list of elements, but randomized.

In general, using `unsafePerformIO` is not recommended.